# How to get an element height in react js with out using any pulgin

Tags: reactjs

I have a div with dynamically changing height. How can I get it's height without jQuery? I want to do so only in react js without using any plugin like the react-height npm plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ref="myDiv">
    ...
</div>
```

And

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    var height = this.refs.myDiv.clientHeight;
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientHeight' of undefined this eroor i am getting

Comment: Did you put the ref attribute on you div correctly ?

Comment: it's working thanks bro

Comment: Just to update this answer, using strings in refs and accessing in this way is deprecated.

You now have to create a ref in your constructor
    this.myRef = React.createRef();

Add it to the element

    <div ref={this.myRef} />;

Then access it using the following

    this.myRef.current;